# Unable to open tcp connection after Cloud Run deploy

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy an API written in go to GCP, Cloud Run, but the `gcloud run deploy` command always fails. Google Log says: `unable to open tcp connection with host '<ip address>:1433'`

Here are the messages from Google Log in relation to the Google SQL connection and the final error:
[image]
[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN go build -v -o simpleapps-backend

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/simpleapps-backend"]
```

client.go

```
package db

import (
    "backend/models"
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlserver"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var Instance *gorm.DB
var err error

func Connect(connectionString string) {
    Instance, err = gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(connectionString), &gorm.Config{})
    //connectionString = "Server=<ipAddress>,1433;Database=<name>;User Id=<userId>;Password=<password>"

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("Connected to Database!")
}

func Migrate() {
    Instance.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})
    log.Println("Database Migration Completed!")
}
```

The app locally runs successfully.

Comment: Is all your code here? If so, have another look at the Cloud Run documentation, especially the runtime contract: you must expose HTTP endpoint. only outgoing TCP connections are possible.

Comment: So you're trying to connect to a SQL Server DB (because of the port). Where is the DB? And cloud run is allowed to connect to that DB?

Comment: The DB is on GCP. I thought if both (DB and Cloud Run) are in Google Cloud, there will be no need for IP address settings.

Comment: Please read my answer to this other post where I list the steps and commands you need to enable cloud run to reach your Cloud SQL db: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488632/error-in-cloud-run-connecting-to-cloud-sql/75495265#75495265.

Comment: A cloud run service does not have access by default to your SQL instance, even providing the role slq client to the service account. Also, docker and Go code are not enough to troubleshoot, please share your yaml or the commands you run to configure the various cloud resources.