# Error in Cloud Run connecting to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run service which is trying to connect to a cloud SQL (postgres) instance. There is a timeout connecting:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 261, in connect_async
    return await asyncio.wait_for(get_connection(), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 458, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc"
```

Checked that:

1. The instance is added in the cloud run config under "Cloud SQL connections"
2. This code works fine locally against the same instance with the same service account. To ensure it uses the service account, not my own login, checked:

```
gcloud auth revoke
```

Check that application doesn't work

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/<serviceaccountcreds>.json
```

Check that application works.

Where do I dig?

The connection is gotten [with the sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/connect_connector.py), nothing fancy.

Comment: Can you please update your question to provide the details of the application code you are using to connect which results in the error you are seeing? (i.e. are you connecting via Public or Private IP, using IAM AuthN or regular db user and password etc.) It would be really helpful :)

Comment: Also feel free to report this as a bug on the library itself: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/new/choose

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to Cloud SQL using TCP to private db instance IP by the VPC Connector. Or by the Cloud SQL Proxy (auto SSL/TSL) to the Cloud SQL Proxy Server available by default in the Cloud SQL instance (auth by IAM).

To test from your local dev PC you do:

```
gcloud components install cloud_sql_proxy
```

create an instance (you have one already..)

```
gcloud sql instances create sql-db ...
```

create a sample db:

```
gcloud sql databases create my_db --instance sql-db
```

connect with:

```
gcloud beta sql connect sql-db --user root
```

remove the default root user and configure a new one that can connect only passing by the Cloud SQL Proxy (if you want that kind of security)

```
gcloud sql users delete root --host % --instance sql-db

gcloud sql users create root  --host "cloudsqlproxy~%"  --instance sql-db

# network "cloudsqlproxy" is shared between 
# cloud sql instance and the proxy server
```

to deploy the service with access to cloudsql:

```
DB_INSTANCE=$PROJECT\:$REGION\:sql-db

gcloud run deploy <SERVICE_NAME> \
  --add-cloudsql-instances $DB_INSTANCE \ 
  --set-env-vars DB="mysql://root@unix(/cloudsql/$DB_INSTANCE)/my_db"
  # all other flags... 
  # DB is alternative to SOCKET_PATH, both for the Cloud SQL client init
```

the role for the service account to work with cloudsql:

```
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding $SERVICE_NAME \  
    --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
    --role roles/cloudsql.client
```

Comment: Thanks, couple questions:

 1) Is the SOCKET_PATH necessary? I was using (cloud connector)[https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#connect-connectors] to connect.

 2) I don't have permissions to set that role; but I am assuming it does exist because, as above, if I log out of my own account, my local connection doesn't work UNTIL I use the keys from the above service account. Which leads me to believe that account does have the right role already. Would that be a fair assumption?

Comment: Also what is the meaning of SOCKET_PATH, is it some predefined env var like PORT? Because [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) does not treat it as anything special, it's whatever is passed in.

Comment: About the service account I think it should work. About the socketpath, it's a way on Linux machines to connect to the db, btw you still need the VPC Connector since Cloud Run is serverless while the Cloud SQL is not, as such it runs under your VPC.

Comment: I get about socketpath being a Unix thing, I was asking specifically if SOCKET_PATH env var has some special meaning to cloud run, or is it whatever var I choose to use if I write code as shown in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#connect-unix-socket).

On the VPC part, does it even matter if I am using Public IP? From the above page:

```
For public IP paths, Cloud Run provides encryption and connects using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy in two ways:

Through Unix sockets
By using a Cloud SQL connector
```

Comment: Pass the SOCKET_PATH to the Cloud SQL client during init... public/private IPs do change the route the service goes  to connect to the db, but you can use  SOCKET_PATH / IAM / --add-couldsql-instances with both... I will try to give a more detailed description on the answer above

Comment: Er, yes; thanks -- except I'm using Postgres (so socket connection looks [a bit different](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connect-unix-socket) ) -- but still I tried that too. In the case of using a socket, I am getting a different stack trace.

Comment: I don't get why the answer was rated -1... Didn't help to troubleshoot?

Comment: it's weird, doesn't seem to work, tried a bunch of things. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75751026/connecting-from-cloud-run-to-postgres-results-in-an-error

Comment: Looks strange... I copied the commands above from a project a work on. More over, they are based on this great book: "Building Serverless Applications With Google Cloud Run: A Real-World Guide to Building Production-Ready Services".

I would cross check your setup and make sure there isn't anything else preventing access.