# Connecting from Cloud Run to postgres results in an error

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

When trying to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres from Cloud Run (using socket connection), I am getting the following error:

```
connection to Cloud SQL instance at 34.86.67.205:3307 failed: timed out after 10s
```

but why 3307? The connection is being attempted to Postgres, with following code:

```
        unix_socket_path = f"/cloudsql/{db_inst}"
        logger.info(f"Using socket path {unix_socket_path}")
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488632/error-in-cloud-run-connecting-to-cloud-sql/75495265#75495265
        # https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connect-unix-socket
        eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine (
            sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
            username=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            database=db_name,
            query={"unix_sock": "{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(unix_socket_path)},
            ),
        )
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488632/error-in-cloud-run-connecting-to-cloud-sql/75495265?noredirect=1#comment133271755_75495265).

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#how-works) explains why 3307 is used. Note the firewall policies that are needed for this. Also is the cloud sql on the same vpc as your cloud run? Just curious why a private ip can't be used?

Comment: Ah, switching to just using private IP worked fine. I'll just ignore chasing this one, thanks.

Comment: @Gregory Golberg, Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.

Comment: FYI there's a Cloud SQL Python Connector that will handle all the heavy lifting for SSL and passwordless authentication: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector.